# Elasticsearch index_options=docs for text data type does not return any search results

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-7

I have been using Elasticsearch 7.6 and PHP client API for all the operations.
I have created elasticsearch index settings and mappings as follows

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'elasticindex',
    'body' => [
        'settings' => [
            "number_of_shards" => 1,
            "number_of_replicas" => 0,
            "index.queries.cache.enabled" => false,
            "index.soft_deletes.enabled" => false,
            "index.requests.cache.enable" => false,
            "index.refresh_interval" => -1
        ],
        'mappings' => [
            '_source' => [
                "enabled" => false
             ],
            'properties' => [
                "text" => [
                        "type" => "text",
                        "index_options" => "docs"
                ]
            ]
     ]
    ]
];
```

I was able to index document using the following code

```
$params = array();
$params['index'] = 'elasticindex';
for($i = 1; $i <=2; $i++) {
        $params['id'] = $i;
        $params['body']['text'] = 'apple';
        $responses = $client->index($params);
}
```

But when I use the following search query

```
  $params = [
        'index' => 'elasticindex',
        'body'  => [
            'query' => [
                'match' => [
                    "text" => "apple"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

$results = $client->search($params);
```

I am getting empty results as follows

```
Array                                                                                                                                                   
   (                                                                                                                                                       
    [took] => 3                                                                                                                                         
    [timed_out] =>                                                                                                                                      
    [_shards] => Array                                                                                                                                  
        (                                                                                                                                               
            [total] => 1                                                                                                                                
            [successful] => 1                                                                                                                           
            [skipped] => 0                                                                                                                              
            [failed] => 0                                                                                                                               
        )                                                                                                                                               

    [hits] => Array         
        (          
            [total] => Array                                       
                (                                                    
                    [value] => 0
                    [relation] => eq
                )           

            [max_score] =>   
            [hits] => Array
                (          
                )     

        )               

)
```

Without creating a static index template, if I try to index, elasticsearch dynamic mapping works well and I am getting the results.

The goal is that I want the elasticsearch to index only document id in its inverted index and not position or offset and I want to retrieve only matching document ids as results. Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want to include the `id` field in your static mapping as well: `"id": { "type": "keyword"},` Use `<host>:9200/elasticsearch/_search?q=*:*` to see if your document has been indexed at all (I'd pick a better index name than `elasticsearch`, btw. :-)

Comment: Can you show me one doc from elastic, don't apply any query filters, just set size as 1 and get one doc and post here.

Comment: @MatsLindh I got the following response for the URL query you have given {"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":0,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}. Does it mean that my document is not getting indexed?

Comment: @jithuthomas I tried to get the document with id 1 and I got the this response Array
(
    [_index] => elasticindex
    [_type] => _doc
    [_id] => 1
    [_version] => 1
    [_seq_no] => 0
    [_primary_term] => 1
    [found] => 1
)

Comment: @MatsLindh Also, I tried creating a static mapping for id field as well but the still same empty response

Comment: You didn't index doc properly. Inelastic doc none of the docs has value apple. I will add an answer how to index sample document and how that can be queried back

Comment: @MohamedAbdullah Correct. Since you're not getting any documents back, an issue occurred when indexing it. The Elasticsearch log should show an error about the document not being indexed properly.

Comment: @MatsLindh the log is clear. i am not getting any error messages and moreover if I use get API, it says found =1.

Comment: Are you querying for the document immediately after sending it to the index? Or is this two separate operations? A document will become available from the `GET` interface _before_ it's being made available for general search - the latter [requires a refresh of the index to happen first](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html). You might need to add `refresh=wait_for` in your indexing request URL.

Comment: @MatsLindh, Yes, it is two separate operations. I am indexing first and then search later

Comment: @MatsLindh you are right. Since I am using this "index.refresh_interval" => -1 the index is not ready for search. once i refreshed the index I got the results. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Good catch! I didn't see that, but that explains it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since the document is being returned by the `get` handler and not the query handler, your index is not being refreshed properly after indexing the document.

As you noted yourself, in your configuration you set:

```
"index.refresh_interval" => -1
```

.. which means that the index is not being refreshed automagically. There's seldom a need to change the refresh interval, except in very high throughput situations or where a particular behavior is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to index doc something like this.

```
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
                    ->setHosts($hosts)
                    ->build();

$params = [
    'index' => 'elasticindex',
    'type' => 'documents',
    'id' => '1',
    'body' => ['text' => 'apple']
];

$response = $client->index($params);
print_r($response);
```

Note: _id you can define dynamically if you want, else id will automatically set by elastic.

And try to get doc via a search query.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "term": {
                    "text": "apple"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want full-text search on this key, set this key property as

```
"properties": {
   "name": {
     "type": "text"
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried as you said. I got the same empty response. Also, mapping types have been removed in elasticsearch 7.0 sp this won't work in the version I am using  'type' => 'documents',

Comment: Are you sure your document getting created correctly? try to retrieve based on _id and check the key `text` present in any one of doc